# Asynchronous Response from python class function

Tags: python, async-await, mailgun, python-class

I was able to successfully use an Mailgun example to send an e-mail, but when converting to a class, the e-mails are not being sent. I am assuming that it has to do with the Asynchronous Response but I am not not sure. This is my first time working with Asynchronous Response and AsyncClient.

This is the class:

```
class Mail:

     def __init__(self):
         self.base_url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{url}'
         self.api_key = '{Key}'
         self.lstAttachment = []
         self.built = False
     def BuildMail(self):
         self.build_request_kwargs = {
                "url": "/messages",
                "method": "POST",
                "data": {
                        #"template": "template_name",
                        "from": "from@address.com",
                        "to": ["to@address.com"],
                        "subject": "Python E-mail Send",
                        "html": "<p>Hello from Python</p>"
                        },
                "files": self.lstAttachment
         }

      async def SendMail(self):
    
         if self.built == True:    
             client = httpx.AsyncClient(base_url=self.base_url, auth=("api", self.api_key))       
             return await self.__MsgSend(client)
    
         else:
             return 'Msg Not Built'


     async def __MsgSend(self, client):
         async with client as C: 
             request = C.build_request(**self.build_request_kwargs)
             response = await C.send(request)
             response.raise_for_status()
         return response
```

Then inside my main script:

```
Email = M.Mail()
Email.BuildMail()
result = Email.SendMail()
```

What I would expect is that the message would get sent and the response to be returned to the main script.

Comment: When using `async` functions, you need to run them using an event loop, e.g. `asyncio.run`. Are you doing that anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting the async function `Mail.SendMail`. Also I don't see anywhere you are using `asyncio.run` Try something like this:

```
async def main():
    Email = M.Mail()
    Email.BuildMail()
    result = await Email.SendMail()

asyncio.run(main())
```